# Correct way to call a service in a controller

Tags: 8, services, page-controller, dependency-injection

I'm new to services (and drupal 8!) and trying to figure out services. I think perhaps I'm just doing the create in an outdated way. What I want do is make my 'hello generator' a service and call it in another controller with the following:

DBController.php

```
namespace Drupal\db\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\db\DbServices\HelloGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class DBController extends ControllerBase
{
private $helloGenerator;

public function __construct(HelloGenerator $x) {
    $this->helloGenerator = $x;
}
public function say($count) {
    $hello = $this->helloGenerator->getHello($count);

    return new Response($hello);
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $x = $container->get('db.hello_generator');
    return new static ($x);
}
}
```

HellGenerator.php

namespace Drupal\db\DbServices;

```
class HelloGenerator {

public function getHello($count) {
    $foo = 4 + 4 + 4;
    return $foo . ' ' . $count;
}

}
```

db.services.yml

```
services:
  db.hello_generator:
     class: Drupal\db\DbServices\HelloGenerator

db.db_says:
  path: /db/says/{count}
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\db\Controller\DBController::say'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: You can follow [document](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-services-and-controllers). It's correct way to call a service in a controller

Answer (score 26):

There are 3 questions here:

1. How to create a controller?
2. How to create a service?
3. How to use services in a controller?

### 1. Create a controller

**1.1 Add a controller class** - you did it. For others [see Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller)

**1.2 Add a routing file** - it looks like this is missing in your code:

my_module.routing.yml

```
my_module.my_route_name:
  path: '/my/path'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::myAction'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

[see Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-routing-file)

### 2. Create a service

**2.1 Add a service class** - you did it.

**2.2 Add a routing file** - you did it although it contains extra code that belongs to the routing file. This is all you need:

my_module.services.yml

```
services:
  my_module.my_service:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Service\MyService
```

[see Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file)

### 3. Use services in a controller

You did it. Here's a reference for others:

**3.1 Override the `create()` method**

The controller class inherits this method from `class ControllerBase`. Its role is to create the controller object. Watch the method argument: it is passed the services container. Extract the services you need and pass them to the constructor:

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $my_service = $container->get('my_module.my_service');
    $other_service = $container->get('other_service');

    return new static($my_service, $other_service);
}
```

**3.2 Initialise services in `__construct()`**

```
public function __construct($my_service, $other_service)
{
    $this->my_service = $my_service;
    $this->other_service = $other_service;
}
```

**3.3 Start using the services**

Comment: I wish the official documentation was more in this style, or at least had a few overview articles that was. Short and concise with a generic example easily translated to the real application.

Comment: A do not forget:
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
in controller class

Comment: While I totally agree with @Nicolaj's comment, this isn't working for me...and I'm not even trying to use a custom service! All I want to do is create a class member variable that holds a static database connection object. I'm used to using systems where connection pooling and never creating more connections than you need is the norm. So how would I implement something similar in a Drupal controller/form?

Comment: You might want to open another question @Kenny83, but have you looked at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Adatabase/8.8.x ? With that you can do something like this: https://gist.github.com/glaux/f4f1517563ddb57fb98b9213802c1569

Comment: @Nicolaj LOL thanks for pointing out the bleedingly-obvious mate :P I'm well-aware of the core database service and that's what I'm trying to return from my `create()` method. I suppose you wouldn't have said that though if I hadn't missed something else that should have been obvious...I guess that service **does** pool connection objects?